# Angular-Passing a parameter from the view to the component to be used by the @ViewChile

Tags: angular, typescript

I have multiple tables in a html file and I require to download those table data to separate excel files. By using the XLSX we can download the data of a table to the excel file using the id of the element. So what Im trying to do is that, send the id of the table to the component using a click event and use that id to be used by the ViewChild to download only that table data as the excel file. How to implement that logic in the controller? Can someone help me with this?

```
 @ViewChild('TABLE', { static: false }) TABLE: ElementRef;   
  ExportTOExcel() {  
    const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = 
    XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(this.TABLE.nativeElement);  
    const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();  
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');  
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'Recieved_List.xlsx');  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TABLE.nativeElement.getAttribute('id')
```

give you the value of "id" attribute. But if you has severals tables perhafs you need use ViewChildren, not ViewChild

if you has a button, you can pass has a reference variable (it's the same that using a ViewChild)

```
<table #myTable>...</table>
<button (click)="doSomething(myTable)">click</button>

doSomeThing(element:ElementRef)
{
    const id=element.nativeElement.getAttribute('id')
    console.log(id)

}
```